# Normalizing chains of .Skip() and .Take() calls

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I'm trying to normalize arbitrary chains of [`.Skip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513.aspx) and [`.Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx) calls to a single `.Skip()` call followed by an optional single `.Take()` call.

Here are some examples of expected results, but I'm not sure if these are correct:

```
.Skip(5)                        => .Skip(5)
.Take(7)                        => .Skip(0).Take(7)

.Skip(5).Skip(7)                => .Skip(12)
.Skip(5).Take(7)                => .Skip(5).Take(7)
.Take(7).Skip(5)                => .Skip(5).Take(2)
.Take(5).Take(7)                => .Skip(0).Take(5)

.Skip(5).Skip(7).Skip(11)       => .Skip(23)
.Skip(5).Skip(7).Take(11)       => .Skip(12).Take(11)
.Skip(5).Take(7).Skip(3)        => .Skip(8).Take(4)
.Skip(5).Take(7).Take(3)        => .Skip(5).Take(4)
.Take(11).Skip(5).Skip(3)       => .Skip(8).Take(3)
.Take(11).Skip(5).Take(7)       => .Skip(5).Take(6)
.Take(11).Take(5).Skip(3)       => .Skip(3).Take(2)
.Take(11).Take(5).Take(3)       => .Skip(0).Take(3)
```

Can anyone confirm these are the correct results to be expected?

---

Here is the basic algorithm that I derived from the examples:

```
class Foo
{
    private int skip;
    private int? take;

    public Foo Skip(int value)
    {
        if (value < 0)
            value = 0;

        this.skip += value;

        if (this.take.HasValue)
            this.take -= value;

        return this;
    }

    public Foo Take(int value)
    {
        if (value < 0)
            value = 0;

        if (!this.take.HasValue || value < this.take)
            this.take = value;

        return this;
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can confirm if this is the correct algorithm?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this used for?

Comment: @NickLarsen: I'm implementing a LINQ Query Provider and need to transform Skip and Take calls into a single offset/count pair.

Comment: Not sure how they behave, but following the presumed logic I believe you should have .Skip(5).Take(7).Take(3) => .Skip(5).Take(3)  (that is take 3 and not 4). You code seems to give this value as well, which I believe to be correct

Comment: @rslite: You're right. Good catch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect scenario for TDD.  Given that you have defined your spec above, this should be *cake* to implement as a series of just a couple of tests.

<s>"Correct" is fairly subjective, but</s> those examples seem sane.

Also, I would normalize out the `.Skip(0)` calls.

Make sure you define your edge cases clearly.  For example,

```
.Take(11).Skip(12).Take(1)
```

should probably be normalized into a `.Take(0)`

---

**Edit:**

The official definition of skip:

> Bypasses a specified number of elements in a sequence and then returns the remaining elements.

And take:

> Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a sequence.

Based on your examples, I think that your test cases are properly following the spec.

Comment: The problem is not so much implementing my own specification, but finding the "correct" specification, since I'm not developing my own query framework but plug into LINQ. Is there any official documentation how LINQ Skip/Take implementations should behave?

Comment: Right, the documentation is not really explicit on how chains should be evaluated, but from those specifications I agree my test cases (that I derived from intuition) look sane. I guess I'll have to make up more test cases to catch all edge cases and update the algorithm accordingly.